# Does Cause of my cracked wall sound correct? Who should Pay? Help

Tags: drywall, studs, crack

[image][image][image]I know nothing about buildings. Please tell me if what I am told sounds correct.

In my 1st floor condo, a long crack, from the ceiling to floor, appeared on my living room wall. The wall bulges out a good 5”, and continues bulging another 4 feet each side of where the crack is. This wall runs the entire length of the left side of the condo and is approximately 32.5 feet long. Behind this wall is the condo next door. The crack appears close to the middle of that wall.
I was away for over a year and the crack happened during this time when I was not there.

I had it investigated by a couple of renovation guys. They cut a hole in the drywall and stuck a light in it and took pictures and video inside the wall. They say this is the issue:

- There are many studs missing in the frame of the wall.
- From the vertical crack to the right, there is a stud appx 34” away.
- From the left of the crack, there is at least 10-12 feet of wall where there are no studs at all.
- This means that there are approx 15 feet between studs.
- There are 3 layers of drywall and they are NOT attached to that stud from mid-way down the wall to the floor (Cannot see above the middle).

This is what allowed the drywall wall to bulge outward a good 4 - 5 inches at the crack continuing 4 feet on each side of the crack.

It seems that the structure /frame of the building was not built correctly. Should there be more studs in the 15 feet where there are none?" especially on the 1st floor of a 3-story building? Should the drywall have been attached to a stud when they built this building?

To fix it – The renovators tell me they need to rip out a large portion of the drywall – at least 8 feet, install some studs, then replace the drywall. An estimated cost of $7500, to $10,000 to fix it. Does that sound right?
BIGGEST QUESTION: Who should pay for this?
It seems to me that it is the condo association’s responsibility since there looks to be a structural flaw in the building when it was built. The contractors say this is the cause - having no studs for 15 feet and not attaching the drywall to the stud that was there. Is that correct?

Would this be a building code violation? Built-in 1972 – Mother was 1st purchaser in 1978

Comment: Sounds like the drywall is buckling because the load bearing studs aren't there, but that sounds so crazy that I wouldn't make the assertion without seeing the thing. Is there a visible sag in the ceiling in the neighborhood of the bulge? Please add some images. From inside the wall too if you have those.

Comment: This sounds like an emergency. Please hurry with some images. And stay out of rooms adjacent to that mess if it's possible.

Comment: ^^ this, and get a lawyer.

Comment: If it's a steel frame building, you don't really _need_ studs in the wall for support, though they are good for other things, like keeping drywall snug. 10k sounds a bit high, I would get more quotes.

Comment: 51 years later, you will not be able to hold anybody liable (if you can even prove that the builder messed up vs. a later renovation). The HOA is in all likelihood an entirely independent legal entity with no responsibility for construction errors. The first owner might have been able to sue the builder shortly after construction, but even six years later, your mother would have had a tough case. Now? Forget about it.

Comment: For a 12 foot long non-structural firewall, materials would probably cost less that 500 USD. The labor would require 2 guys for 1 day and 1 guy coming back for a second day. That's a "non-structural firewall." Your quoted price implies work that would be far less superficial, i.e. a "structural firewall."

Comment: This screams of a demand to have the condo association assume responsibility. ( condo associations have insurance for this type of thing.) If they will not, consult an attorney

Comment: It sounds very bizarre, but measure from the floor to the top of the 15' gap in the wall studs. If it's ~12" shorter than the height of the interior wall, then there's some sort of header across this gap which means that structurally, it's likely not an issue. Yes, it'll need studs to support the drywall, but not to support the building. Sounds like you're at the point of just tearing the drywall off your side, since it will need to be done to do _any_ work, so feel free to do so.

Comment: is this a commo wall with the neighbor?  Your jurisdiction might differ but where I live the cost would be borne by both owners of the wall.

Comment: @nobody.  We are the first owners (my Mother and I) of the condo and there has never been any renovation.    How would you ever know there was an issue until something like this happens?  You don't buy a condo and then cut holes in the drywall just to look.  I don't know if this has happened to anyone else on the first floor . Not sure how I would find out

Comment: @Tiger Guy. No its not a common wall. The neighbor has a wall on the other side of the studs

Comment: "The neighbor has a wall on the other side of the studs" Like drywall, or concrete separating your wall from theirs?